# Did I damage my frame by removing a sticker?

Tags: frames

[image]

I’ve just bought a new bike with a matt finish, and peeled off a sticker from the top of the frame - but this revealed a shiny finish underneath.

Is this a problem, and do I need to do anything about it?

I’m wondering if the frame is now vulnerable to weather etc. on this spot, or if there’s a risk the coating could start to peel away from the edges.

Comment: Unless it's a carbon frame, there's no way to do structural damage removing a sticker.  For steel or aluminum you might damage the finish, but that would only be a cosmetic issue.  In this case it appears that the sticker adhesive remains on the tube, and a brief cleaning job with something like "Goo Gone" is what's needed.  (Or the time-honored chemical for this -- hair spray.)

Answer (score 1):

The shine is likely the residue from the sticker adhesive. I would apply some rubbing alcohol on a soft cloth and see if it comes off. As you haven't damaged the actual finish, it will be fine. I had a similar finish on a Diamondback Response. After its' first wash I waxed it. I thought I had ruined the matte finish. When the wax wore off the original finish returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don’t think it’s residue, the matt surface is ever so slightly raised above the shiny section. At a guess it looks like the decals were applied and then the whole frame was coated with a finish.

Comment: For removing adhesive, use oil (_e.g.,_ WD-40), not alcohol. Clean the oil up afterwards with some Windex.

Answer (score 0):

Your frame is fine. It's not clear to my why the finish is different underneath, but in any case, the finish is purely cosmetic: nearly all bicycle paintjobs are powdercoating (*i.e.,* powder baked onto the frame), which is extremely durable.

It's not going anywhere, and even without a paintjob, your aluminum frame would not corrode in the elements.